# How to check a job is completed before it's been created using kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I can use `kubectl wait --for=condition=complete --timeout=<some time> job/<job-name>` to wait for a job in completed state. However, if the job has not yet been created (sometimes, it's due to k8s takes some time to schedule the job), kubectl will exit with error immediately.

Is there a way to wait for the job been created and then transit into completed state? What's the most common way to do this in industry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubectl wait` does not include the functionality to [wait on a non existent resource yet](http://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/83242).

For anything complex try and use a [kube API client](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/). Run a `watch` on a resource group and you receive a stream of events for it, and continue on when the event criteria has been met.

If you are stuck in shell land, `kubectl` doesn't seem to respect SIGPIPE signals when when handling the output of a `kubectl get x --watch` so maybe a simple loop...

```
timeout=$(( $(date +%s) + 60 )) 
while ! kubectl get job whatever 2>/dev/null; do
  [ $(date +%s) -gt $timeout ] && exit 1
  sleep 5
done
```

Comment: This is really nice. Thanks, Matt!

Comment: Hmm, looks like `while ! kubectl get job whatever 2>/dev/null;` cannot be used to determine whether a job been created or not. @Matt

Comment: In bash, we can use `while [[ -z $(kubectl get job whatever 2>/dev/null) ]]` instead.

Comment: That construct uses the exit status of the command. `if ! false; then echo notfalse; else echo false; fi` it's fairly common across shells and I use it with kubectl regularly. What was the issue?

Comment: There was a `return` in there for the timeout, but that's only for when this is used inside a function.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I accidentally added `set -o errexit`. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=created --timeout=<some time> job/<job-name>
```

***Edit***: If I'm not mistaken, `kubectl wait` is still experimental anyway - but the condition you name should match whatever you're expecting in a standard status output.

***Second Edit***: wrong character update

Comment: `--for` needs an `=`. And this doesn't work yet - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/83242

Comment: Oh I see. I've never used it for created, but that explains it pretty well. Thanks! Then maybe perhaps a bash script would suffice. I don't feel like looking into any of my old scripts at the moment, but might tomorrow